# mingw64 + sublime 3 input output files not working

Tags: c++, c++17, sublimetext3, setup-project, mingw-w64

I am trying to set up an environment for competitive programming. I have successfully installed mingw 64 with sublime 3. My code is able print hello world in the console. However, I am unable to read inputs and output into the input and output files. I am following the instructions [here](https://blog.codingblocks.com/2016/setting-up-sublime-text-for-competitive-coding/) and this is the c++ code that I am trying to run.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){

    #ifndef ONLINE_JUDGE
    freopen("input.txt", "r", stdin);
    freopen("output.txt", "w", stdout);
    #endif

    cout << "Hello world";
    int var;
    cin >> var;
    cout << var;
}
```

I have the integer 5 in my input.txt file. When I build with c++ single file and run, nothing happens and the console just says `[Finished in 5.6s]`. I hoping that the code will read inputs that I place in the input.txt file and output them to the output.txt file. When I remove the 2 freopen code, Hello world is printed onto my console. May I know what am I doing wrong here? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and it turns out windows defender was blocking edit to output.txt file (A new feature has been added in windows defender called Controlled folder access). Check if your directory is not included in that feature. Are you using the default build system for c++ in Sublime? Check paths are correct