# Not able read from input output files in Sublime Text 3

Tags: c++, c, g++, sublimetext3

I have successfully installed MinGW and have tried running cpp programs from command prompt and it runs perfectly. In Sublime I tried using default build system 'C++ Single File', it prints simple statements in the console below but it cannot take input. After building the programs with 'cin' commands the program does not show any output and I try giving input in the console below and press ENTER but nothing happens. Then I found a method of using 'freopen' command to take input from a file and output to a different file. But the programs runs successfully but doesn't output anything in the output file. Same problem -- [mingw64 + sublime 3 input output files not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65812574/mingw64-sublime-3-input-output-files-not-working)

After this I tried many other build files I found on web but none of them work.

```
{
"cmd": ["g++.exe", "-std=c++17", "${file}",
        "-o", "${file_base_name}.exe",
        "&&", "${file_base_name}.exe<input.in>output.out"],
"shell":true,
"working_dir":"$file_path",
"selector":"source.cpp"
}
```

The output.out file is always empty. I have input and output files in same directly and I think it is reading input correctly because when I delete the input file it gives an error that it cannot find the input file. I even tried using text files (input.txt, output.txt) after moding build system code but it doesn't work.
I have many other build codes but none of them works.
I tried running `g++.exe -std=c++17 contest1a.cpp -o contest1a.exe && contest1a.exe<input.in>output.out` in command prompt but the output.out file is still empty.
I replaced first line with `"cmd" : ["g++ -std=c++14 $file_name -o $file_base_name && timeout 4s $file_base_name < input.in > output.out"],` but it gives error because I think .exe is not suffixed which I tried adding and program runs but output is still empty.

Why is 'freopen' not working, why is any build not able to write in output file ?

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out Windows defender has a new feature 'Block Folder Access' which blocked my program from modifying the output file. I wasted one day solving this issue smh